# How to remove part of a binary image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to process images of cows to estimate their body weight, but when I process the images, the processing includes the head in the binary image. I am looking for a way to just estimate the body.

I am using the hue value of the images, then converting to binary and removing all background information.

```
csv_img = pd.read_csv(subdir + '\\' + csv_name + '.csv', skiprows=115, skipfooter=175, engine ='python')
img = cv2.imread(subdir + '\\' + img_name + '.png')[115:305,0:848]
cv2.imshow('color', img)
cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows() 

#COnvert to hue, saturation, and value
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
                       h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv_img)
                       hsv_split = np.concatenate((h,s,v),axis=1)
                       cv2.imshow('hue', h)
                       cv2.waitKey(0) 
                       cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

RGB image:
[image: RGB Image]

Processed image:
[image: Processed Image]

I have tried cropping the image, but am struggling to work on how to use read_csv to skip the columns to match the cropped image. Is there anyway to exclude the head from the image processing or crop this image?

Comment: `csv_img = pd.read_csv(...)` Why use CSV as an image format? The PNG image conveys all the same information, right? Or is there information in the CSV which is not present in the PNG?

Comment: @Katie How do you generate the csv file?

Comment: never ever use false-color pictures as data. they're visualizations, and generally useless for any kind of measurement. work to find the **depth map** that underlies this false-color picture.

Comment: @NickODell The CSV contains the depth information for each pixel.

Comment: @user3435121 The csv file is generated from converting a .bag file. The .bag file comes from a Intel RealSense depth camera.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the CSV file contains the depth information at each pixel.